# Should I create my own settings.json in an Azure Function project?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

We have an Azure Function project which requires parameters. At the moment, these parameters are stored in Azure Function's application Setting.

To run the azure function locally, we used to do this:

```
var id = GetEnvironmentVariable("Id");
///var id=12345;
```

Basically on local machine, we will just uncomment the hard coded line to get the value;

I don't really like it, so I did this:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("settings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();
```

I put all settings into a settings.json and read it from there.
However, as these settings are already available in azure function's appsetting section, I will have to manually delete them from azure portal (or change the arm template).

What is the preferred way to store settings for azure function? In appsetting section or in a config file like I did? Or maybe some different way?

Comment: You probably are looking for local.settings.json - this file will be used locally - as the production settings will be used in production env. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=macos%2Ccsharp%2Cbash#local-settings-file

Comment: Think you are right. This is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

In fact, as **Carlos Alves Jorge** says, the function app will read settings from local.settings.json on local by default. And on azure it will read settings from configuration settings by default.

By default, publication neither upload local.settings.json to Azure, nor makes modification on Application settings based on that local file, hence we need to update them manually on Azure portal.

If you are using VS to publish your azure function, there is a easy way to change the settings from local to azure.(edit the publish profile.)

[image]